# Is there a problem if I put braces in html code in jsx syntax?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In JSX syntax, I know that brace is used when writing JavaScript expressions.

```js
const name = 'Josh Perez';
const element = <h1>Hello, {name}</h1>;
ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Even if you look at the react official documentation, you do not use braces in the script as above. Since this is not JavaScript code, why not use it with {element}? Does an error occur if I use it with {element}?

Comment: Here `element` is a component, so you should use if like component.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use
 `` <h1>{`Hello, ${name}`}</h1> ``
like a javascrypt string